# Element height increased after .animate() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created the following accordion slider:

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8a5dsaqx/1/)**

After I click on one of the list items, it triggers the `.animate()` function. My problem is, that after animation start rendering, the browser scroll-bar appears on the side for just a second. This is because the height of the list items increased a bit, but I can't figure it out why is it doing this.

Comment: I don't see that in Chrome.

Comment: I take that back. If I have a fairly low panel height for the accordion I do see it.

Comment: Adding a `body { overflow: hidden; }` CSS style seems to prevent this artefact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `overflow: hidden` on the `#vaccordion` element, and also `height`. In this case I set the `height` in percent, so you need also define a `height` to the parents of `#vaccordion` too (`html`, `body`).

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#vaccordion {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/8a5dsaqx/2/